# jquery - multiple image upload form with remove option

Tags: php, jquery

I want some suggestions regarding image upload form like facebook and tumblr which can preview multiple images with caption and description fields with each image and if user wants to remove any image before uploading he is able to do that. So please suggest me how to achieve this i have tried this but i am having issue with removing image from input type = file as it is **readonly** i am facing problem when i am submitting the form on server. Please give me your ideas i really need help i have deadline of this month i am badly stuck in this problem. I am using php and jquery. **Note: Please dont suggest any plugins.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have face same problem like you

now i have found solution for that i think this will be useful for you to solve your problem

```
 <input type="file" id="attachfile" name="replyFiles" multiple> <!--File Element for multiple intput-->
 <div id="#filelist"></div>
 <script>
    var selDiv = "";
    var storedFiles = []; //store the object of the all files

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false); 

    function init() {
       //To add the change listener on over file element
       document.querySelector('#attachfile').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
       //allocate division where you want to print file name
       selDiv = document.querySelector("#filelist");
    }

    //function to handle the file select listenere
    function handleFileSelect(e) {
       //to check that even single file is selected or not
       if(!e.target.files) return;      

       //for clear the value of the selDiv
       selDiv.innerHTML = "";

       //get the array of file object in files variable
       var files = e.target.files;
       var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);

       //print if any file is selected previosly 
       for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++)
       {
           selDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='filename'> <span class='removefile'  data-file='"+storedFiles[i].name+"'> " + storedFiles[i].name + "</span></div>";
       }
       filesArr.forEach(function(f) {
           //add new selected files into the array list
           storedFiles.push(f);
           //print new selected files into the given division
           selDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='filename'> <span class='removefile'  data-file='"+storedFiles[i].name+"'> " + f.name + "</span></div>";
       });

       //store the array of file in our element this is send to other page by form submit
       $("input[name=replyfiles]").val(storedFiles);
 }

 //This function is used to remove the file form the selection   
 function removeFile(e) {
        var file = $(this).data("file"); //To take the name of the file

        for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) { //for find the file from the array
            if(storedFiles[i].name === file) { 
                storedFiles.splice(i,1);   //remove file from the list
                break;
            }
        }

        //now store the list of the all remaining file in our element name which will submit with the form
        $("input[name=replyfiles]").val(storedFiles);    
        $(this).parent().remove();  
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").on("click", ".removefile", removeFile);
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//I added event handler for the file upload control to access the files properties.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

//To save an array of attachments
var AttachmentArray = [];

//counter for attachment array
var arrCounter = 0;

//to make sure the error message for number of files will be shown only one time.
var filesCounterAlertStatus = false;

//un ordered list to keep attachments thumbnails
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = "thumb-Images";
ul.id = "imgList";

function init() {
  //add javascript handlers for the file upload event
  document
    .querySelector("#files")
    .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
}

//the handler for file upload event
function handleFileSelect(e) {
  //to make sure the user select file/files
  if (!e.target.files) return;

  //To obtaine a File reference
  var files = e.target.files;

  // Loop through the FileList and then to render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; (f = files[i]); i++) {
    //instantiate a FileReader object to read its contents into memory
    var fileReader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information and apply validation.
    fileReader.onload = (function(readerEvt) {
      return function(e) {
        //Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
        ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt);

        //Render attachments thumbnails.
        RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt);

        //Fill the array of attachment
        FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    // readAsDataURL: The result property will contain the file/blob's data encoded as a data URL.
    // More info about Data URI scheme https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
  document
    .getElementById("files")
    .addEventListener("change", handleFileSelect, false);
}

//To remove attachment once user click on x button
jQuery(function($) {
  $("div").on("click", ".img-wrap .close", function() {
    var id = $(this)
      .closest(".img-wrap")
      .find("img")
      .data("id");

    //to remove the deleted item from array
    var elementPos = AttachmentArray.map(function(x) {
      return x.FileName;
    }).indexOf(id);
    if (elementPos !== -1) {
      AttachmentArray.splice(elementPos, 1);
    }

    //to remove image tag
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find("img")
      .not()
      .remove();

    //to remove div tag that contain the image
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .find("div")
      .not()
      .remove();

    //to remove div tag that contain caption name
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .parent()
      .find("div")
      .not()
      .remove();

    //to remove li tag
    var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#imgList li");
    for (var i = 0; (li = lis[i]); i++) {
      if (li.innerHTML == "") {
        li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
      }
    }
  });
});

//Apply the validation rules for attachments upload
function ApplyFileValidationRules(readerEvt) {
  //To check file type according to upload conditions
  if (CheckFileType(readerEvt.type) == false) {
    alert(
      "The file (" +
        readerEvt.name +
        ") does not match the upload conditions, You can only upload jpg/png/gif files"
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  //To check file Size according to upload conditions
  if (CheckFileSize(readerEvt.size) == false) {
    alert(
      "The file (" +
        readerEvt.name +
        ") does not match the upload conditions, The maximum file size for uploads should not exceed 300 KB"
    );
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }

  //To check files count according to upload conditions
  if (CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) == false) {
    if (!filesCounterAlertStatus) {
      filesCounterAlertStatus = true;
      alert(
        "You have added more than 10 files. According to upload conditions you can upload 10 files maximum"
      );
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
}

//To check file type according to upload conditions
function CheckFileType(fileType) {
  if (fileType == "image/jpeg") {
    return true;
  } else if (fileType == "image/png") {
    return true;
  } else if (fileType == "image/gif") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

//To check file Size according to upload conditions
function CheckFileSize(fileSize) {
  if (fileSize < 300000) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

//To check files count according to upload conditions
function CheckFilesCount(AttachmentArray) {
  //Since AttachmentArray.length return the next available index in the array,
  //I have used the loop to get the real length
  var len = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < AttachmentArray.length; i++) {
    if (AttachmentArray[i] !== undefined) {
      len++;
    }
  }
  //To check the length does not exceed 10 files maximum
  if (len > 9) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

//Render attachments thumbnails.
function RenderThumbnail(e, readerEvt) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.innerHTML = [
    '<div class="img-wrap"> <span class="close">&times;</span>' +
      '<img class="thumb" src="',
    e.target.result,
    '" title="',
    escape(readerEvt.name),
    '" data-id="',
    readerEvt.name,
    '"/>' + "</div>"
  ].join("");

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "FileNameCaptionStyle";
  li.appendChild(div);
  div.innerHTML = [readerEvt.name].join("");
  document.getElementById("Filelist").insertBefore(ul, null);
}

//Fill the array of attachment
function FillAttachmentArray(e, readerEvt) {
  AttachmentArray[arrCounter] = {
    AttachmentType: 1,
    ObjectType: 1,
    FileName: readerEvt.name,
    FileDescription: "Attachment",
    NoteText: "",
    MimeType: readerEvt.type,
    Content: e.target.result.split("base64,")[1],
    FileSizeInBytes: readerEvt.size
  };
  arrCounter = arrCounter + 1;
}
```

```css
/*Copied from bootstrap to handle input file multiple*/
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Also */
.btn-success {
  border: 1px solid #c5dbec;
  background: #d0e5f5;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2e6e9e;
}
/* This is copied from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/css/jquery.fileupload.css */
.fileinput-button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fileinput-button input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
  font-size: 200px;
  direction: ltr;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumb {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul.thumb-Images li {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 120px;
}

.img-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img-wrap .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #d0e5f5;
  padding: 5px 2px 2px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-wrap:hover .close {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.FileNameCaptionStyle {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label style="font-size: 14px;">
   <span style='color:navy;font-weight:bold'>Attachment Instructions :</span>
   </label>
   <!--To give the control a modern look, I have applied a stylesheet in the parent span.-->
   <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
   <span>Select Attachment</span>
   <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif,"><br />
   </span>
   <output id="Filelist"></output>
</div>
```